# SQL | Scala | jooq | table contains Array[Long] and Long | get pairs of one value from the array with the Long of the row

Tags: sql, scala, jooq

Hi I'm using joog with scala and I have table which has on field which is long array and one field which is Long something like this:

```scala
Table Question{
    id: Long
    subQuestionIds: Array[Long]
}
```

I would like to get pairs of `(<qustion id>, <sub question id>)`
according to a List of sub questions Ids

in short i want to give an input which is list of sub questions ids and get back all question ids for each sub question id.

how can I do that?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Can you show the actual DDL of your table, rather than pseudo-DDL?

Comment: class Question(tableName: String) extends JooqTable(tableName) {
  val id: TableField[JLong] = createBigIntField("id")
  val subQuestionsIds: TableField[Array[String]] = createVarcharArrayField("sub_questions_ids")
}

Comment: at this point Ill be happy even to get a pair of the question id and the array of the sub questions ids if the requested id is in the sub questions ids array

Comment: You can edit your question with updates. But can you answer my question? I need to know in order to give you an answer. By RDBMS, I mean e.g. PostgreSQL? By DDL, I mean your `CREATE TABLE` statement defining the table.